# MonoTouch iPad iTunes Submit - Beta?

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes, xamarin.ios, beta

Using MonoTouch 2.0 and MonoDevelop 2.2.2 I created an iPad app.

It is set to the 3.2 OS

When I submit the app it says that this binary was created with a beta version.

I have the newest XCode/SDK

Comment: Are you *sure* you have the newest SDK? Current version as of this question is plain 3.2, no GM or beta tag associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in MonoDevelop which has been resolved for some time now.

Comment: And this question was posted back in April 2010 :-)

Comment: I'm aware, but we have people asking us about old questions quite frequently, so I decided to back fill so people can google them and get the answer :)